# Heroku with caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku

I'm using page caching within my application. Everything works fine locally. But after I push changes to  heroku server. Caching expiration won't work. I use sweepers to track and expire cached pages.

Here's config for caching in the production.rb

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store
#config.cache_store = :file_store, 'tmp/cache/'
I tried both ways nothing work.
```

Maybe there's some specific configuration which I don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:memory_store` won't work with Heroku, and `:file_store` will only work in .`/tmp` on the current Dyno (Dynos don't know about each other).  They're working on supporting Memcached in beta and you can check out the other docs on taking advantage of Varnish: http://docs.heroku.com/http-caching

Answer (score 1):

Heroku converts regular rails page caching (which writes files to disk, no-go on their read-only filesystems) to use cache-control HTTP headers instead. Of course with this you lose the ability to expire the cache. You can only do `:expires_in => some.minutes`.

Check out action caching instead.